# Prencher um vetor de tamanho[10] com outros dois vetores[5] nas posições 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 e 1, 3, 5, 7, 9

Tags: array, c++

Questão:

> Criar dois vetores com tamanho 5 e um vetor de tamanho 10;
>
> Preencher os dois vetores de tamanho 5 com números inteiros inseridos
>   pelo teclado;
>
> Após preencher os dois vetores de 5 posições o conteúdo deles deve ser
>   passado para o vetor de 10 posições de forma que:
>
> - Utilize um laço de repetição na leitura e na passagem dos valores;
> - O conteúdo do primeiro vetor deve ficar nas posições 0, 2, 4, 6, 8;
> - O conteúdo do segundo vetor deve ficar nas posições 1, 3, 5, 7, 9.

Eu apenas não sei de que forma passar esses dois vetores de tamanho 5 naquelas posições pro vetor de tamanho 10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int vet1[5], vet2[5], vet3[10];

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        //cout << "Primeiro vetor de tamanho 5: \n";
        cout << "Informe um valor: ";
        cin >> vet1[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        //cout << "\nSegundo vetor de tamanho 5: \n";
        cout << "Informe um valor 2: ";
        cin >> vet2[i];
    }
```

Comment: Oi Magazak, tudo bem? Como isso tem cara de exercício de faculdade vou tentar te ajudar com o problema sem dar a solução final. Se você precisar de mais ajuda me fale. O segredo desse exercício é que você precisa tomar uma decisão dentro do laço. Índices pares (ou seja, onde `i % 2 == 0`) devem ser lidos de `vet1` enquanto índices ímpares devem ser lidos de `vet2`. Outra questão é que você precisa mapear os índices entre 0 e 9 de `vet3` para os respectivos índices entre 0 e 4 de `vet1` e `vet2`. Você pode fazer isso dividindo `i` por dois, e.g. `vet3[i] = vet1[i / 2]`.

Comment: Ou, fazer o for de 0 a 4, e colocar os elementos de vet1 e vet2 nas posições 2*i e 2*i + 1 do vet3...

Comment: Uma alternativa é fazer: `for (i=0; i<5;i++) { vet3[2*i] = vet1[i]; vet3[2*i+1] = vet2[i];}`.

Comment: Muito obrigada a todos pela ajuda, eu conseguiii

Comment: Nick parecido com o meu hein kkkk

Comment: Sério? Kkkkkkk qual é o seu?